# How to change the keyboard layout of LTSP clients in 13.10

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, keyboard-layout, ltsp, localization

I am trying to change the keyboard layout for ubuntu 13.10 ltsp clients.

I edited /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/i386/lts.conf (which was empty after the install).

What works is de/german, but this is the keyboard setting that the system was installed with:

```
[default]
XKBLAYOUT=de
```

I can also change the file to

```
[default]
XKBLAYOUT=us
```

This changes all clients to an us-keyboard. But how can different clients/users use different layouts or even switch during a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/i386/lts.conf:

> [default]
>
> XKBLAYOUT="de,us"
>
> XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

To switch between them by alt+shift pressing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple layouts same as X server:

```
[default]
XKBLAYOUT="de,us"
```

Consult the X.org documentation for valid settings.